# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Horizontal Forms

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code. However the form doesn't work as intended. It has the labels/inputs below one another rather than next to one another

> Email (Label)
>
> Email (Input)
>
> Password (Label)
>
> Password (Input)

Rather than

> Email (Label)        Email (Input)
>
> Password (Label)     Password (Input)

As per this example http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEMPLATE</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you mean "doesn't work intended"?

Comment: Updated with an example but I did briefly explain what I meant - "It has the labels/inputs below one another rather than next to one another"

Comment: so you mean , the label and text box are not coming horizontally ... right?

Comment: Are you referencing the NEW bootstrap files? Because it works fine when I copy paste your code in bootstrap fiddle: http://bootply.com/81202

Comment: @JanuszJasinski Maybe the path for your css files are off

Comment: How embarrassing - I was viewing it in my portrait browser and it resized!

Comment: Why devote people who are trying to help?..

Comment: it's just deceiving because the bootstrap defaults these input widths to 100% :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the paths to your CSS files. When using your code (copy pasted) in bootstrap fiddle it works as expected(http://bootply.com/81202). Since your CSS files aren't included as suspected it enables a default markup.